# Uncaught TypeError when calling an action creator with data from a form input

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am new and would really appreciate your help. I have a form with four inputs (firstName, lastName, position and email) and want to pass the data the user puts in to the state to create an user object. But I always receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Maybe I did map the state wrong? I honestly don't know.

Here is my code:

The form I created which takes the users input:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import validate from './validate';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin(); //Needed, otherwise an error message is shown in the console

//Texteingabefeld
const renderTextField = ({input, label, meta: {touched, error}, ...custom}) => (
  <TextField
    hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
);

const renderUsers = ({fields, meta: { touched, error }}) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary"
              type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"/>Add User
      </button>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>

      <Field name="firstName" component={renderTextField} label="First Name"/>

      <Field name="lastName" component={renderTextField} label="Last Name"/>

      <Field name="position" component={renderTextField} label="Position"/>

      <Field name="email" component={renderTextField} label="Email"/>


    {fields.map((user, index) =>
    <div key={index}>
        <Field name={`firstName${index}`} component={renderTextField} label="First Name"/>

        <Field name={`lastName${index}`} component={renderTextField} label="Last Name"/>

        <Field name={`position${index}`} component={renderTextField} label="Position"/>

        <Field name={`email${index}`} component={renderTextField} label="Email"/>

        <button className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                type="button"
                title="Remove User"
                onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"/>
        </button>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
);

const UserCreation = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <FieldArray name="users" component={renderUsers}/>

      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-success"
                type="submit"
                disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send" />
          Submit
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-danger"
                disabled={pristine || submitting}
                onClick={reset}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'UserCreationForm',
  validate
})(UserCreation);
```

The Component which fires the action when the user submits the form:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import UserCreation from '../components/UserCreation';
import { addUser } from '../actions/UserActions';

class UserControlPage extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {

  }

  handleSubmit=(values) => {
    addUser(values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div>
            <legend>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> User creation
            </legend>
            <UserCreation onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({addUser}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

  return {
    users: state.users
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserControlPage);
```

The action creator:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {ADD_USER} from './index';

export const addUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    payload: {
//      id: id,
      firstName: user.payload.firstName,
      lastName: user.payload.lastName,
      position: user.payload.position,
      email: user.payload.email
    }
  };
}
```

The reducer:

```
import {ADD_USER} from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default function UserReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return [...state, {
//        id: action.id,
        firstName: action.firstName,
        lastName: action.lastName,
        position: action.position,
        email: action.email
      }];

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you `console.log(user)` in the action, what you get?

Comment: I get the following object:

Object
email: "stack@overflow.com"
firstName: "test"
lastName: "stack"
position: "overflow"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action creator has to get data without the `payload`, like this:

```
export const addUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    payload: {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      position: user.position,
      email: user.email
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things wrong. First of all, you're attaching your data to a `payload` object inside of your action, but you're not reading from that object in your reducer. So in the reducer, for example, where you have `action.firstName`, it should actually be `action.payload.firstName`.

Secondly, what you're returning from the reducer is not right. Your initial state is an object, but you're returning an array. So your state is all kinds of messed up as soon as you mutate state. Try this instead:

```
import {ADD_USER} from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default function UserReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Update**

I see yet another problem. In this code, you're referencing `user.payload`, which does not exist.

```
export const addUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    payload: {
//      id: id,
      firstName: user.payload.firstName,
      lastName: user.payload.lastName,
      position: user.payload.position,
      email: user.payload.email
    }
  };
}
```

It should be `user.firstName`, `user.lastName`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at addUser (UserActions.js:21)
    at UserControlPage._this.handleSubmit (UserControlPage.js:47)

Comment: That's because you're referencing `user.payload`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Changing the action creator to

```
    export const addUser = (user) => {
    return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    payload: {
       firstName: user.firstName,
       lastName: user.lastName,
       position: user.position,
       email: user.email
    }
  };
}
```

and the reducer to

```
const INITIAL_STATE = [];

export default function UserReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return [action.payload, ...state];

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

solved the error.